# Wrap my code inside a promise or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

im having this question inside my head the whole day, im a beginner nodejs developer and i am wondering when should i wrap my code inside a promise to use async/ await  and when should i not...
lets take and example i have two files :

index.js

```
        var mailer = require('../mailer')
        var mailOptions = mailer.mailOptions(......)
        mailer.sender(mailOptions)
```

mailer.js :

```
module.exports.mailOptions = (.......) => {
....
}

module.exports.sender = (mailOptions) => {

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, callback(err, info))
}

function callback(err, info) {
}
```

should i wrap the sender function inside a promise to call it like this :

```
await mailer.sender(mailOptions)
```

or my example is good and i don't need the promise ?
hope that you understand what i mean

EDIT :

I am using nodemailer package from npm : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer

Comment: You should do whatever you are more comfortable with. The async / await pattern is easier to read, but you are not required to use it.

Comment: Is this a question about using promises vs. callbacks or a question about when to use async/await (which requires promises already)?

Comment: It looks like you aren't providing `sendMail` with a function, but rather the result of calling `callback()` that doesn't seem right. Also, is this Node Mailer? Doesn't it already return a promise if you don't pass a callback?

Comment: @link0047 talking about the easier to read, i think await mailer.sender(mailOptions) or mailer.sender(mailOptions) are both easy to read... if not, explain where the easy things comes

Comment: @Mark_M yeah i verified that and its not working, i just give the `sendMail` an anonymous function and its working now... so at this point i cannot give it a named function ?

Comment: @ettayebmohamed yes you can give it a names function but don't *call* the function -- it will call the function when it's done. In your example it would just be: `transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, callback)`

Comment: @Mark_M oooh this is a basic thing and i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs, Node Mailer will return a promise if no callback is given (https://nodemailer.com/usage/). This makes everything very nice to work with. For example you can do this in mailer.js:

```
// just return the promise from sendMail() 
module.exports.sender = (mailOptions) => transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
```

Then you can use it with `await` or with `then()`

```
try{
    let info = await mailer.sender(mailOptions)
    console.log(info.messageId) // etc
} catch(err){
    console.log("Error:", err)
}
```

or

```
mailer.sender(mailOptions)
.then(info => console.log(info.messageId)
.catch(err => console.log("Error:", err)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically what you think looks best.  As you noticed, `async` and `await` use promises under the hood.  Generally I'd say promises and `async`/`await` look best when you have a clear linear order in which you want things to occur, whereas callbacks look better when things could happen in differing orders or could keep being called back on multiple occasions.  In your example I'd say `await` and a promise would work quite well because the logic is linear: "send the email, then do something."

Comment: aaah did you mean that i have to wrap that inside a try catch to stop other things if the mail is not sent ?!

Comment: With promises you can use a `.catch` in the call chain and with `async`/`await` you can use `try`/`catch`.  With callbacks the handler will get the error param.

Comment: so the utility of `async/await` is that with `try/catch` i can stop other things when i got an error ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would want to wrap a code with promise object only when the code is **asynchronuous**.  Otherwise it won't make much sense.

Here is the Promise definition by mozilla:

> Promise represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

Await key word is used to make synchronuous code to wait on a promise or async function/variable (which in fact is wrapped with promise behind the scenes).

In your case, if mailer, behind the scenes, returns a promise, you can use await on it (like you did), and there is no need to wrap it with another promise object. On the other side, if mailer is not returning a promise, you need to wrap it with promise to be able to await on it.

In both cases, it depands how mailer is implemented. If mailer is a synchronuous behind the scenes, it won't make any change or sense to await on it since js engine will any how execute it synchronuousley.

Please provide more information about mailer module so we can see the whole picture.